# Parsing XML with same name tags giving null in Android

Tags: android, xml

I am facing a problem in parsing the following XML:

```
<key>key 1</key>
<string>string 1</string>
<key>key 2</key>
<string>string 2</string>
<key>key 3</key>
<string>string 3</string>
```

I have written the following code but I get data only of the first  tag in TextView, not the data of tags string2 and string 3. How to parse XML with same name tags?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Context mContext = this;
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);

    try {      
         DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
         AssetManager assetManager = mContext.getAssets();
         InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("abc.xml");   
         Document doc=db.parse(inputStream);
         doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
         NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("string"); 


 for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) { 
     tv.setText( "\n\n"+ nodeList.item(i).getChildNodes().item(i).getNodeValue()+"\n"); 
     }


        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your starts from this condition...change your condition from...

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
```

to...

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength()-1; i++) {
```

**Update:**

Change this....

```
tv.setText( "\n\n"+ nodeList.item(i).getChildNodes().item(i).getNodeValue()+"\n");
```

to...

```
tv.setText( "\n\n"+ nodeList.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()+"\n");
```

Comment: Still getting data only in first tag.

Comment: How can I avoid some string tags to be included? Like, if I want to include string tags only after tags key 1, key 2 and key 4 and not the string tags after key 3 and key 5. I'll compare the value of key tags to a string, if condition satisfied, append the next node text, otherwise how to ignore the data of next node ? Please help.